# Nested element won't remove parent class

Tags: jquery, parent-child, removeclass

The class is set on an `<li>` by it being clicked. Now a nested element (`<button>`) will not remove the class from it's parent.

Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.pickOne li').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });

      $('.settingsCancelBtn').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');
      });
    });
```

and the HTML is like so:

```
<div class="fromCamp pickOne four">
                <ul class="four">
                    <li class="first bus"><a href="#" alt="By Bus"></a>
                        <div>
                            <p class="cmInfo">Arrive between 9 AM and 11 AM. Read these <a href="#">additional instructions</a>. <a href="#">Driving Directions</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#">Tilefishes</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#">Bluefishes</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#">Tigerfishes</a></p>
                            <button class="cmCancelDeleteButton settingsCancelBtn" type="button">Cancel</button>
                            <button class="cmGoButton settingsSaveBtn" type="button">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="second car"><a href="#" alt="By Car"></a>
                        <div>
                            <p><a href="#">Remoras</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#">Tilefishes</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#">Bluefishes</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#">Tigerfishes</a></p>
                            <button class="cmCancelDeleteButton settingsCancelBtn" type="button">Cancel</button>
                            <button class="cmGoButton settingsSaveBtn" type="button">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="third plane"><a href="#" alt="By Plane"></a>
                        <div>
                            <p class="cmInfo">Arrive between 9 AM and 11 AM. Read these <a href="#">additional instructions</a>. <a href="#">Driving Directions</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#">Tilefishes</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#">Bluefishes</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#">Tigerfishes</a></p>
                            <button class="cmCancelDeleteButton settingsCancelBtn" type="button">Cancel</button>
                            <button class="cmGoButton settingsSaveBtn" type="button">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="fourth stayOver"><a href="#" alt="Staying Over"></a>
                        <div>
                            <p><a href="#">Remoras</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#">Tilefishes</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#">Bluefishes</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#">Tigerfishes</a></p>
                            <button class="cmCancelDeleteButton settingsCancelBtn" type="button">Cancel</button>
                            <button class="cmGoButton settingsSaveBtn" type="button">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="cmClear"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, here's what's happening:

Because your button in contained in the LI, when you click the button, it removes the class, and then the event continues to propagate and reapplies the class.

So it IS removing; its just reapplying instantly. So add

```
  // Dont forget to put the e in function()
  $('.settingsCancelBtn').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');

    // This is the new line!
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. Great catch Erik, and good solution... I would +1 but I am outta votes for today :(

Comment: Wow, can't believe that someone else had the exact same issue, with the exact same solution. Great going, Erik!

Answer (score 0):

So, minutes after I posted this, my buddy presents a solution. Break points... who knew. :)

Because I was initially selecting the `<li>`, when I clicked on a child of it to remove the active class, it removed it, and then immediately added it again.

The solution was to select the `<a>` inside the `<li>` initially (it's set to `display:block` and covers the same space the `li` does.)

Silly me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.pickOne li a ').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      });

      $('.settingsCancelBtn').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');
      });
    });
```

Comment: aww you posted this right before I solved it for you! Its a common mistake in JS - just remember that the event continues to propagate outwards until you catch it, hold it down, and bash it over the head with a hammer repeatedly ... err .. I mean until you stop it.

Comment: thanks man! It's a good learning experience I suppose. Violence is the answer I suppose. :)